# Get the progress of an Advantage Database query in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, advantage-database-server

I've searched and searched, but can't find out how to get the progress of a query in Delphi.  I've found some information for the Advantage .NET data provider but could use some help with Delphi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the [AdsRegisterCallbackFunction](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/index.html?ade_adsregistercallbackfunction.htm) method. Here's a quick example I use for displaying progress during creating indexes for a TAdsTable; it works exactly the same way for progress in a `TAdsQuery`:

```
implementation

var
  // Holder for reference to progressbar on form, so it can be
  // accessed easily from  the callback - see below
  PB: TProgressBar = nil;  


// replacement for Application.ProcessMessages, since we don't have 
// access to the Application from the callback either

procedure KeepWindowsAlive;
var
  M: TMsg;
begin
  if PeekMessage(M, 0, 0, 0, pm_Remove) then
  begin
    TranslateMessage(M);
    DispatchMessage(M);
  end;
end;

// The callback function itself - note the stdcall at the end
// This updates the progressbar with the reported percentage of progress
function ProgressCallback(Percent: Word; CallBackID: LongInt): LongInt; stdcall;
begin
  if PB <> nil then
    PB.Position := Percent;
  KeepWindowsAlive;
  Result := 0;
end;

// The button click handler. It registers the callback, calls a function 
// that creates the index (not shown here), and then unregisters the callback.
//
// As I mentioned above, it works the same way with a TAdsQuery.
// You'd simply assign the SQL, set any params, and register the
// callback the same way. Then, instead of calling my CreateIndexes
// method, you'd Open the query; it will call the progress callback
// periodically, and when the query finishes you just unhook the
// callback as shown here.
procedure TCreateIndexesForm.CreateButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Grab a reference to the progress bar into the unit global, so we don't
  // need a reference to the form by name in the callback.
  PB := Self.ProgressBar1; 

  // AdsTable is a property of the form itself. It's set
  // during the constructor. It's just a `TAdsTable` instance.
  // The index info is set in that constructor as well (tag, 
  // expression, type, etc.).
  AdsTable.AdsRegisterCallbackFunction(@ProgressCallBack, 1);
  try
    CreateIndexes;
  finally
    // Unhook the progress callback
    AdsTable.AdsClearCallbackFunction;
    // Clear the outside reference to the progress bar
    PB := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Note that the callback must be a stand-alone procedure (as shown above), not a form method. I've shown a way to not have to hard-code access to a particular form name by using the unit global reference to the progress bar.

Comment: I'll include the help file links to as an additional FYI.  
AdsRegisterCallback: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11/index.html?ade_adsregistercallbackfunction.htm
Callback Functionality/Caveats
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11/index.html?master_callback_functionality.htm
detailed in the help, but also of note, if the registered function(ProgressCallback) returns a non-zero value it will signal to abort the operation.